# Importing data from one MYSQL table into another -- the first table doesn't have the same amount of rows as second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've read and searched for the answer to this before asking. I am trying to import the data of 4 columns from one MYSQL table into another MYSQL table that has more than 4 columns. As I expected I got

> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'

Does anyone know a trick to get around this issue?

### Postscript

I've already tried using

```
INSERT INTO new_table(colname1,colname2,colname3,colname4)
SELECT 'colname1','colname2','colname3,'colname4' FROM old_table;
```

that generates error

> 1054 unknown column 'colname1' in 'field list

I've also tried

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
SELECT 'colname1,'colname2,'colname3','colname4' 
FROM old_table;
```

which generates error

> #1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to `INSERT INTO` a table with a different number of columns, then you should specify what columns you want to insert into.

So if you have a table with 20 columns and you know you want to insert into column 1, column 10, column 15 and column 20, then you explicitly name those columns in your insert.

Similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (col1, col10, col15, col20)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM Table1
```

Comment: I've tried that. I updated my original question to reflect what happens on two different statements I've tried. When I try the way you're suggesting, which is the correct  way, I get  error 1054 unknown column 'colname1' in 'field list.  I am stumped. Thank you for helping :).

Comment: @RyanSatterfield Can you edit your question with the table structure and some sample data?

Comment: @RyanSatterfield Are you using single quotes around your column names?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify into which colums you want to insert

```
insert into destination_table (col1, col2, col3, col4)
select * from source_table
```

Think about it: How should the DB engine know which source column has to fill what destination column?

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99392/1)

### Update

Remove the quotes around the column names

```
INSERT INTO new_table(colname1, colname2, colname3, colname4)
SELECT colname1, colname2, colname3, colname4 
FROM old_table;
```

If you want to escape a column name then use backticks (`` ` ``) instead.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I updated my question with more explanations and SQL statements.

Comment: @RyanSatterfield: Remove the quotes around your column names. Otherwise it would be interpreted as string. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO new_table(colname1,colname2,colname3,colname4)
SELECT 'colname1','colname2','colname3,NULL FROM old_table;
```

Just enter NULL wherever there is No column available to match the